# jQuery form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

My form works as it should and i receive the emails from it but if you hit submit without entering data you get an error box informing you what you of required fields - however my submit button stays greyed out, so even if you then fill in those fields you cannot submit the form without a refresh.

code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#success').hide();

    $('#contactform').submit(function() {
        var action = $(this).attr('action');

        $('#contactform #submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled').after('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" class="loader" />');

        $("#message").slideUp(750,function() {
            $('#message').hide();

            $.post(action, { 
                name: $('#name').val(),
                email: $('#email').val(),
                phone: $('#phone').val(),
                subject: $('#subject').val(),
                comments: $('#comments').val(),
                verify: $('#verify').val()
            },
            function(data) {
                document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
                $('#message').slideDown('slow');
                $('#contactform img.loader').fadeOut('fast',function(){$(this).remove()});
                $('#contactform #submit').attr('disabled',''); 
                if(data.match('success') != null) $('#submit').hide();

            });
        });

        return false; 
    });
});
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You should remove disabled attribute enterily
`$('#contactform #submit').removeAttr('disabled'); `

Comment: Unfortunately It still stays disabled :(

Comment: try this `if(data.match('success') != null)  {$('#submit').hide();}else{$("#submit").removeAttr('disabled');}`

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `disabled` attribute works by existence. By that I mean that the very inclusion of the disabled attribute causes the element to be disabled.

Replace:

```
$('#contactform #submit').attr('disabled','');
```

with:

```
$('#contactform #submit').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: I think you are right with this, but i'm not sure that the validation he is talking about is done server side.

Comment: Unfortunately It still stays disabled :(

Answer (score 0):

This is because the submit button is disabled after you hit the submit:

```
  $('#contactform #submit').attr('disabled','disabled').after('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" class="loader" />');
```

you shoul re-enable it if the validation fails like this:

```
 $('#contactform #submit').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: Unfortunately It still stays disabled :(

Comment: does the line with 'removeAttr' get executed? Check with Firebug/Firefox or Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [removeAttribute](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) function.

I think it will solve your problem.

(As `<input type='text' disabled='disabled' ---->` and `<input type='text' disabled --->` are same.
Using removeAttribute will render something like `<input type='text' --->` and your problem will be solved)

Comment: Unfortunately It still stays disabled :(

Answer (score 0):

did you check if this script actually runs to the point where it should remove or update the attribute?

Comment: still the same...how annoying!